# Optimizing a query on Mysql 5.5.24

Tags: mysql, performance, query-performance

I am trying to optimize the query

```
SELECT
  CONCAT(lastname, ', ', title, ' ', firstname) AS fullName,
  e.lastname,
  e.firstname,
  e.email,
  e.userType,
  e.userID
FROM
  employee e,
  employee_categories ec
WHERE
 1 = 1
```

which is taking 20 seconds to run. The employee table has 6000 records(number of employees) and employee_categories table has 1000 records. Both tables are indexed and index is the primary key in both tables. The index type is unique and index method is BTREE.

I tried

```
SELECT
  SQL CACHE CONCAT(lastname, ', ', title, ' ', firstname) AS fullName,
  e.lastname,
  e.firstname,
  e.email,
  e.userType,
  e.userID
FROM
  employee e,
  employee_categories ec
WHERE
  1 = 1
```

I set query_cache_size to 32MB, ensured have_query_cache is set to Yes, query_cache_type is set to 1. I am using MySql 5.5.24 with InnoDB as storage engine

What else can I try?

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you really mean to do a Cartesian product of the two tables? Your result will have 6 million rows, so 20 seconds seems very reasonable!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without some way of tying the two tables together, you are asking for 6 *million* rows (6000*1000).

Instead of `FROM employee e, employee_categories ec`, you need something like

```
FROM employee e
JOIN employee_categories ec  ON e.category = ec.category
```

AND... be sure `category` (or whatever it is called) is indexed (perhaps `PRIMARY KEY`) in one of the tables.

Those changes should speed it up by a factor of 1000 or so.

The Query cache is irrelevant (and generally should be turned off).

Comment: Thanks a lot Rick. I had to do a left join, but now the query runs in 4 seconds. Thanks again.

Comment: Glad you are happy.  I was expecting much more than 5x improvement.  (Although, I did not really expect 1000x.)

Comment: Thanks Rick, I used Query cache thinking it would speed up things and found that when searching for optimizing a query on MySQL database. I will need to search and read some blogs/books on tuning databases. Would you recommend any? Thanks for helping the community.

Comment: There are a number of good books out there, but I am biased toward [my blogs](http://mysql.rjweb.org/) which cover a number of common issues.  The blogs on `Memory allocation` (which includes Query cache) and `Cookbook for Creating Indexes` are perhaps most relevant to this thread.